# npm not working

Tags: pi-4

I have a pi4 and am very new to it so

I have installed npm and nodejs but it wont run any packeges, I get an "throw err; cannot find module ´internal/util/types´.

I run ´npm -v´ and get the same messge as above.
I run ´apt-get -f install npm´ and get npm is alredy newst version (5.8.0+ds6-4).
I run ´nodejs -v´ and get v10.15.2.

Sorry if this is a very badley explaind problem, my knowlege in this is at a very basic level.

Comment: what research have you done?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by removing everything I could think of.
Then I installed it from scratch.
Here are the commands I did:

```sh
sudo rm -rf ~/.nvm
hash -r

# Remove latest node version
sudo npm uninstall -g n

# Remove n
cd ~/src/n && sudo make uninstall && cd .. && sudo rm -r n

# Remove latest nodejs version
sudo apt-get purge -y nodejs npm

# Remove nodejs-legacy version
sudo apt-get purge -y nodejs-legacy npm

sudo apt -y autoremove

# Remove nodejs files
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/n
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/node
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/npm
sudo rm -f /usr/bin/node
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/n/versions/node
```